# How to dynamically add to table after submitting form

Tags: javascript, html

This is my code currently, how could I change the current code So I'm able to input data from the form after submitting then adds to the table below, I know I got to do more with JS to achieve this, but can't find anything online that will help me accomplish what I want to do

Edit: What Im trying to accomplish which I cant seem to find online resources to help me, to be exact when I put in the movie name and date, after submitting the values should be put in the table below the form

```
<html>
<head>      
<title>Movie Details</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
function movieName(){
    var name = document.getElementById("movie").value;

    if (true)
    {
        alert(name);
    }
}

function date(){
    var released = document.getElementById("dateRelease").value;

    if (true)
    {
        alert(released);
    }
}
</script>

</head>
<body>

<div id="add">

    <form name="movieAdd" method="GET">

        <fieldset>

            <legend>Movie Details</legend>

            <p>
                <label for="movie">Movie Name:</label>
                <input type="text" required placeholder="Movie Name"             name="movie" id="movie"/>
            </p>

            <p>
                <label for="date">Date Released:</label>
                <input type="date" required name="date" id="date"/>
            </p>

        </fieldset>

        <p>
            <input type="submit" name="submitButton" value="Submit">
        </p>
    </form>
</div>

<table id="movieTable" width="350px" border="1">
<tr>
    <th>Number</th>
    <th>Movie Name</th>
    <th>Date Released</th>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: can explain properly what u need Exactly ??

Comment: its not that its not working, I just cant find online resources that can help me accomplish my goal. 

What im trying to do is When you put in the movie name and date, after submitting this will be added to the table below the form

Comment: Is there any `server-side` manipulations ? If __NO__, Why do you need form to be submitted ?

Comment: @Gajeel you want its store in data base and without reloading the page it will visible in you table? Am i right

Comment: @RayonDabre sorry no there isn't I'm just trying to play with html and js for self learning

Comment: @AkhileshSingh that is correct

Comment: picturize the i/p and o/p in your question so it will be helpful to understand...

Comment: Try Ajax to save the Data and after success you manipulate the table.

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend using jQuery (http://jquery.com/).  You can use it to easily select elements from your form, for example:

```
var movie = $('#movie').val();
```

You can then easily append a table row with the necessary data, for example:

```
var $td = $('<td>').text(movie);
$('#movieTable').append($td);
```

I hope this points you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using php, then you can use post method to achieve this. once the form is posted you can populate the table.

```
if(isset($_POST['submitButton'])){
     echo '<table id="movieTable" width="350px" border="1">';
      echo '<tr>';
      echo  '<th>'.$_POST['moviename'].'</th>';
      echo '</tr>';
      echo '</table>';
}
```